# using AsyncFileUpload in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to use AsyncFileUpload in ASP.NET MVC 2. Or maybe there is an equivalent (that uses no browser plugins)?

Answer (score 0):

[jquery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) is such a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

http://www.uploadify.com/

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/03/image-preview-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx